# Python: How to list bucket location for each IBM COS bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I am using the [Python SDK for IBM Cloud Object Storage](https://github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-python/) and want to loop over all visible buckets and return their location. The issue I am facing is that for some buckets an error `The specified bucket does not exist.` is returned. According to [this SO answer it is caused by different storage types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652258/ibm-cloud-cos-using-s3-api-get-bucket-location-returns-bucket-not-found).

How can I handle it nonetheless and at least get the location for accessible buckets? Here is the rough Python code:

```
cos = ibm_boto3.client('s3',
                    ibm_api_key_id=api_key,
                    ibm_service_instance_id=service_instance_id,
                    ibm_auth_endpoint=auth_endpoint,
                    config=Config(signature_version='oauth'),
                    endpoint_url=service_endpoint)


# Call COS to list current buckets
response = cos.list_buckets()

# Get a list of all bucket names from the response
buckets = [bucket['Name'] for bucket in response['Buckets']]
print(response)

for bucketname in buckets:
   print(bucketname, cos.get_bucket_location(Bucket=bucketname)['LocationConstraint'])
```

Comment: How you do it will depend on how you can tell whether a bucket is accessible or not. Is there a property that might be missing that you can check on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to this workaround for now:

```
def locations(buckets):
   locs={}
   for b in buckets:
      try: 
         locs[b]=cos.get_bucket_location(Bucket=b)['LocationConstraint']
      except: 
         locs[b]=None
         pass
   return locs
```

It tries to fetch the location. If it fails, **None** is assigned which nicely translates to **null** when converted to JSON.